# Changing base path for Next.js app exploded the entire thing on production server but not development server/local build?

Tags: css, docker, nginx, next.js

TL;DR I changed my base path from "/" to "custom-subpath" and while everything runs great on my development server/local build, it doesn't function at all and looks like it's missing a ton of CSS on the production server.

Please bear with me, formulating this question is going to be difficult as I have very weak understanding of endpoint/servers.

So I've built an app with Next.js that's being hosted on a docker image with nginx.

Originally, the app was being hosted on a temporary domain, and all of the pages I made for the app were in the "pages" directory of my Next project. This made routing easy, I would just add something like href="page1" anywhere I wanted and my app would navigate to them. When it was deployed like this, everything worked splendidly.

Now that I have a permanent domain, I wanted to set this project up with the root being a subpath of this permanent domain.

To do this, I renamed the "index.js" file that was being recognized as "/" before to "custom-subpath" and added the following code to my next.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    basePath: "/custom-subpath/",
};

module.exports = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/",
                destination: "/custom-subpath/",
                permanent: true,
            },
        ];
    },
};

publicRuntimeConfig: { //Don't know if this is necessary but I saw it somewhere online so I thought it couldn't hurt
    basePath: "/custom-subpath" || "";
}
```

I then took the rest of the pages and put them in a directory called "custom-subpath", which means I can route to them with Next using something like href="custom-subpath/page1". (This was tested a long time ago so I knew it worked)

I tested this on the development server as well as my locally built project and everything worked fantastically. Running the server and navigating to "localhost:3000/" automatically routed to "localhost:3000/custom-subpath", everything that already existed in my code that would navigate back to the index page correctly navigated to "localhost:3000/custom-subpath", and I was ecstatic.  No build errors, nothing.

Then, the server was redeployed with the updated code and the entire project seemingly broke.
Images are missing (fixed this part I think, I've removed them from the images below for privacy reasons), CSS is seemingly entirely absent, and the login button wouldn't even attempt to route to the next page.

Images of the local development server(top) vs the hosted docker image(bottom):

[image: Before]

[image: After]

The coloring and shapes and such are there because of Material UI's SX prop (I think), but it looks like any and all actual CSS is missing. (The whitespace between this paragraph and the bottom of the second image is actually part of the page, not a space in my post).

I guess my question is - what did I do wrong? Something is clearly very wrong with the code, but why isn't that showing up at all on my development server/ build?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I renamed the index.js file to "custom-subpath". When you set basepath in next.config.js, it automatically expects index.js to be whatever that basepath is, no need to rename it.